# ORA-01789: Query block has incorrect number of results columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this (top Query) that works perfectly, but I'm trying to add the second query to work with it which all it does is calculates the sum per day. I'm still relatively new to writing SQL, and I was wondering if someone can help assist with this? I tried using a UNION but kept getting Query block has incorrect number of results columns

Thank you in advance!

`Select POSTING_DATE,
       MISTI_ID,
       MATERIAL,
       CASE
         WHEN MTL_DESC IS NULL THEN
          SHORT_TEXT
         ELSE
         MTL_DESC
         END AS MTL_DESC,
       VEND_NAME1,
       RECIPIENT,
       QTY,
       AMT_GRP_CURR
  From COST_DM5_DAILY
  Where COST_CENTER = 'C1003'
  ORDER BY POSTING_DATE DESC`

***This is the second Query***

`Select SUM(AMT_GRP_CURR), Posting_date
  From COST_DM5_DAILY
  Where COST_CENTER = 'C1003'
  group by Posting_date
  order by Posting_date desc`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Can't you do it in just one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that number and datatype of columns used in UNION have to match. Have a look at this simple example:

Missing `col2` in 2nd `select`:

```
SQL> select 100 col1, 'a' col2 from dual
  2  union
  3  select 300 col1           from dual;
select 100 col1, 'a' col2 from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns
```

Wrong `col2` datatype in 2nd `select`:

```
SQL> select 100 col1, 'a' col2 from dual
  2  union
  3  select 300 col1, sysdate  from dual;
select 100 col1, 'a' col2 from dual
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
```

Finally, the way to go:

```
SQL> select 100 col1, 'a' col2 from dual
  2  union
  3  select 300 col1, 'b' col2 from dual;

      COL1 C
---------- -
       100 a
       300 b

SQL>
```

---

As of your code, it seems that you can't do that - at least, it wouldn't make sense as you'd have to `GROUP BY` *all* columns used in the `SELECT` column list that aren't aggregated:

```
select posting_date,
       misti_id,
       material,
       case
         when mtl_desc is null then short_text
         else mtl_desc
       end as mtl_desc,
      vend_name1,
      recipient,
      qty,
      amt_grp_curr,
      --
      sum(amg_grp_curr) sum_result
from cost_dm5_daily
where cost_center = 'C1003'
group by 
       posting_date,
       misti_id,
       material,
       case
         when mtl_desc is null then short_text
         else mtl_desc
       end as mtl_desc,
      vend_name1,
      recipient,
      qty,
      amt_grp_curr
order by posting_date desc;
```

---

Perhaps an analytic form of the `SUM` function might help. For example:

```
select posting_date,
       misti_id,
       material,
       case
         when mtl_desc is null then short_text
         else mtl_desc
       end as mtl_desc,
      vend_name1,
      recipient,
      qty,
      amt_grp_curr,
      --
      sum(amg_grp_curr) over(partition by posting_date order by null) sum_result
from cost_dm5_daily
where cost_center = 'C1003'
order by posting_date desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query has 8 columns in its result set, while the second only has 2; which explains the error message. The first also has the date column first, which is a secondary issue - the data types of the columns have to match in each position (or be implicitly convertible, at least).

You need to swap the order of the columns in the second query (so date comes first), and then decide which position you want the sum in - and add nulls for the rest (probably; or some other fixed value).

```
Select POSTING_DATE,
       MISTI_ID,
       MATERIAL,
       CASE
         WHEN MTL_DESC IS NULL THEN
          SHORT_TEXT
         ELSE
         MTL_DESC
         END AS MTL_DESC,
       VEND_NAME1,
       RECIPIENT,
       QTY,
       AMT_GRP_CURR
  From COST_DM5_DAILY
  Where COST_CENTER = 'C1003'
union all
Select Posting_date,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       SUM(AMT_GRP_CURR)
  From COST_DM5_DAILY
  Where COST_CENTER = 'C1003'
  group by Posting_date
  order by Posting_date desc;
```

You might want additional terms in the `order by`, since you'll have multiples for the same date.

This is probably something your application/reporting layer should be doing.